# Anisotropic vs Isotropic Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, harmonic-oscillator

IS there any quantum mechanical process which can take over an anisotropic commensurate harmonic oscillation to an isotropic one?

Mathematically, this kind of transformation is available.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1666379

But, is there any physical situation where this kind of transformation can take place? 
Any response towards this questions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ultracold atoms, and in particular Bose-Einstein condensates, are frequently trapped in magnetoptical potentials which have a quadratic form. If you had a two-dimensional system and changed the trap frequencies in the two directions you would be able to control the anisotropy of the potential very precisely (and of course when the frequencies are equal you would have an isotropic quadratic potential). You can see some examples of how trap potentials can be realized here https://doi.org/10.1016/bs.aamop.2017.03.002

Comment: Thanks a lot. The link is not opening. However, Manually change in frequencies lead to anisotropic case to isotropic is a very trivial thing.But I need some physical phenomena.

Comment: Sorry, I dropped a character from the url. It should work now. So you want a situation where the change occurs spontaneously?

Comment: Yes. I am interested in spontaneous transition.